# Missing project.pbxproj file

Tags: xcode

I'm can't find the project.pbxproj file. Can anyone tell me where this is located?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Usually it is situated inside corresponding YourProjectName.xcodeproj package - it is a folder but looks like an ordinary file in MacOS's Finder - you can go into it right-clicking and choosing 'show package contents' option.

Comment: I had this unexpected issue and found that for some reason when changing ownership, this file had been put in my gitignore file

Comment: Yes, i end up copying from another project and adding into the package contents
then worked for me