# How to Add project.pbxproj File For Json Framework in iOS and Suitable Framework

Tags: ios, json, frameworks, pbxproj

I am using xcode 4, Compiler version LLVM GCC 4.2.

I have been trying different versions of Json framework in hope that if anyone of them can be included without errors. First I tried SBJson 3.1, but it gave me nearly 170 warnings and some errors, for which I could not find successful solution. Then I tried Json 2.3.1(iphone) , 2.3.2 and finally SBJson 3.0... For all these 3 versions, Xcode is raising an error for missing project.pbxproj file:

`Project/Users/<username>/Desktop/<project name>/SBJson_v3.0/__MACOSX/SBJson_v3.0/SBJson.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.`

I located this by following steps from:
[Missing project.pbxproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054063/missing-project-pbxproj-file)

*My question here is that how and in which folder will I add this file*? I just tried to copy it in SBJson_v3.0 folder and added it to project, but still it is not detecting this file.

Also it is raising same error for `DisplayPretty.xcodeproj` and `TweetStream.xcodeproj` in SBJson 3.0

Please can anyone provide proper steps to eliminate this error...? And plz also tell that which framework is most suitable for my xcode and its compiler?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors sound like they are related to you including too much of what you downloaded. Those errors are probably related to the demos and such included in the SBJson package that you shouldn't have in your project. If you just want the SBJson abilities I would recommend just adding the SBJson files to your project directly. You can just copy over everything under the /Classes folder and build.

Comment: Thank you @rooster117 for your quick reply. I will inform you about result soon.

Comment: It worked!! You saved me from a big trouble and headaches. Thank you very much :)