# Localization native development region, base localization and Appstore language (bundle)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I do understand that "Localization native development region" is a fallback for languages that are missing in the project.

I do understand that the language shown in the Appstore comes from the bundle and its directories structure, but how can i make the base localization match the development region?

On Xcode 6 the default setting is English for development language with base localization checked & the same in the info.plist.

I've already read the suggested questions & answers but i still haven't a clear answer.

The directory structure of that project has only one dir called Base.lproj, if I change the info.plist localization native development region doesn't affect the fact that the project is recognized to have an English development language.

If I add a localization according to the new value in the info.plist, remove the base localization, remove the English localization(moving to trash leaving no trace), reselect the base localization saying that the base localization refers to say Spanish as a reference language, the bundle is still recognized as English.

How can i set the base internationalization to match another language than English?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the development language in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871815/changing-the-development-language-in-xcode)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This a trick more than an answer, a real solution is really hard to find if you want to keep the Base localization.
Right after the creation of a new project, open the xcodeproj file manually in a text editor.
After few line you'll find something like that:

```
developmentRegion = English;
            hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
            knownRegions = (
                en,
                Base,
            );
```

By changing manually `developmentRegion` and the reference in `knownRegions`, is possible to obtain in the info tab under xcode 6 a localization like yourlanguage-Development language.
I've filed a radar (n° 19438250) to Apple asking a dropdown menu' to chose the development language of the project or clarify that problem.