# How do I change the Development language in Xcode before internationalizing my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization

I'm taking over an app that was written entirely in French. Strings are hardcoded in French in the code, and all the messages in the storyboard are in French. But the initial development region in `Info.plist` was left to English. So I changed `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to `fr` so that it matches the real language that was used. But XCode keeps telling me that my Development language is English:

[image: XCode 6.3.2 project Info tab]

How can I correct that? The goal is to be able to activate Base Internationalization and have it use French as the Base language instead of English.

Answer (score 42):

The following procedure worked for me, but it includes manually editing `project.pbxproj` file:

1. Quit XCode
2. Open the `project.pbxproj` file with your favorite text editor
3. Update the following section (near `developmentRegion`):

**OLD:**

```
    developmentRegion = English;
    hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
    knownRegions = (
        en,
        Base,
    );
```

**NEW:**

```
developmentRegion = fr;
            hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
            knownRegions = (
                fr,
                Base,
            );
```

I've created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladimirkofman/AppInFrench) with a sample project that was initially created with **English** as default Development Language, and then updated by the procedure above to use **French** as Development Language.

[image: Project ScreenShot]

Comment: I was finally able to change the development language, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

I might have figured it out.

I have built an app in Swedish, but the development language is set to English.

I edited `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` manually. There are two lines like this:

```
91C8245918BDFA6100A9972F /* en */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; name = en; path = en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

and this section:

```
developmentRegion = English;
hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
knownRegions = (
        en,
        Base,
);
```

Changing all "en" to "sv" like this:

```
91C8245918BDFA6100A9972F /* en */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; name = sv; path = sv.lproj/InfoPlist.strings; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

and

```
developmentRegion = Swedish;
hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
knownRegions = (
        sv,
        Base,
);
```

and moving the file `MyProject/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` to `MyProject/sv.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` seems to have fixed it. Now the "Development Language" shows up as Swedish, and I can add an English translation.

After adding the translation, the storyboard has an expand-triangle where the base language is the existing Swedish version, and the translation is a strings-file in english.

[image: The storyboard have an English translation. Yay.]

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to develop the project in my own "developer" language by using placeholders instead of real texts in example "WLAN_NOT_AVAILABLE" inside of NSLocalizedString which later on will be translated in different languages including english, off course. I do not like when I must write whole sentences right in the code.

I did just open *.pbxproj file inside of *.xcodeproj folder and changed the following line to:

```
developmentRegion = Base;
```

After that English was no more set as development language and I was able to treat it as any one else. This gives you as developer the possibility to write short text placeholders and delegate the correct spelling to another in your team.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood the question. AFAIK, it's quite simple to achieve what you want using the Xcode's GUI as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Ruby script to change the development region in the Xcode project using the cocoapods libraries:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'Xcodeproj'

filename = ARGV.first

raise "Argument '#{filename}' is not a valid .xcodeproject" unless filename && File.directory?(filename) && File.extname(filename).downcase == ".xcodeproj"

puts "Region to set: "
region = $stdin.gets.chomp

project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(filename)
project.root_object.development_region = region
project.save

puts "#{project.path}", "development_region = #{project.root_object.development_region}"
```

https://www.ralfebert.de/snippets/ios/xcode-change-development-language/

Answer (score 0):

Select the `Info.plist` file under `Supporting Files` group in the Project Navigator (on the right). Then, in the editor-view in the `Localization native development region` click on the up-and-down-arrows on the right of 'English' and select `France`.

[image: Open base-language selection]

This should be it. Although, Xcode sometimes doesn't update the "Info" view of the project settings.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the "Base" language. This only defines what language will be used if none of the user's preferred languages exists.

Comment: @geon: Where did you read this? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW2 and https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW4 does not mention the selection of default translation if no translation for user-language is available.

Comment: @dergab: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-130430-BAJJHDJH

Comment: @geon: Well, nicely spread information fragments. So it has todo with both, default-translation selection (at run-time) and base-language definition for UI-files (at design-time/ pre-compile-time).

Comment: @dergab: The CFBundleDevelopmentRegion (or "Localization native development region") isn't mentioned anywhere in the document you linked to. Why do you think it affects the "Base Internationalization"?

Comment: @geon: But "development language" is mentioned. And as there is no other reference, how else should the development language be determined if not via development region? But you might be right. This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871815/changing-the-development-language-in-xcode shows how to set the "development language", and there seems no relation with development region.