# NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel localization

Tags: nsopenpanel, swift4.2, nssavepanel

I use non English (Czech) UI of macOS Mojave and XCode 10.0 where I want to use NSOpenPanel and NSSavelPanel in my Swift 4.2 application. Some text items used in panels I can localize via NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel classes properties but some (like Cancel button for example) I can't. Any suggestin how to localize those?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the Czech localization?

Comment: Nope. How I could? Ofcourse macOS is in Czech

Comment: Go to Project info and add a localization. Or [change the development language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695493/how-do-i-change-the-development-language-in-xcode-before-internationalizing-my-a/32742143)