# Localization in Swift, Base, German, English, what's the correct way to do it?

Tags: localization

I have a project which is nearly completed.
The language I used in Storyboard and in code is German. I use Base localization (which is German because the Strings in Storyboard and Code are German). The App is also localized in English.

Basically I want that every non-German user can use my App in English but I also want to use German language in Storyboard and code.

For that, I set the Base localization to English (I set the language to "EN" in project.pbxproj, and I set the language to "United States" in the Plist file).

What I want is working but I think this is not the correct way to do it because in my current configuration Xcode thinks that my Base is English (because I set it to English) but in fact it's German.
If I would set the Plist file and the project.pbxproj file back to DE users which are not German and not English would have to use my App in German. Or am I wrong?

What's the correct way to achieve that German users can use my App in German and all others should see the English version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the base language to English, add German for additional languages, so the APP for any users uses German on the phone will display German. Otherwise, the APP for all users who do not use German will display the base language, which is English. I hope this will help you.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32813159/1360389) to set up the development language on XCode.

Comment: This is pretty much what I already have. But is this really the correct way to do it? I’m afraid that the best way is to change all Strings in Storyboard and Code to English...

Comment: @lololarumpel Yes, I think so. Because the base language is used for all the users without the supported languages in your APP. Any users who not use German should display English in the APP. _This is so-called “Base” language. If you are making your app for global market, normally you want to use English texts in this “Base” language resources._ This statement is mentioned in this [article](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I hoped for an easier solution. I will do that...