# Xcode localization issue

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I am new to Xcode swift programming and have developed an app with german as my development and base language. I did this by setting `developmentRegion = de;` in my *project.pbxproj* file.

Later on I added an english localization which works fine and I also set `Localization native development region` to `English` in the *info.plist* file. The reason is because the language should be english in all other regions which are not german.

Now I have the problem that if I switch the device language back to german the app will appear in english too.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You mentioned that you switched the *device language* but did you switch the **device region** too?

Comment: @CodeBender yes I switched the device region to germany too but that doesn't work either

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871815/changing-the-development-language-in-xcode/36926728