# Change App language localization in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have searched a lot and went through multiple similar questions but haven't found any that solves my issue: I have published an app to the Apple AppStore via iTunes Connect.

As my native language is not English I want the app language to be German instead of English so I selected as language German in iTunes Connect everywhere possible.
Still, in the App Store it displays English as language even though I have changed it in iTunes Connect.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the app actually _localized_ for German?

Comment: in Xcode itself? no I wasn't able to do that properly

Comment: then iTunes is right: the app is in English, the default

Comment: how to change it? I didn't find any current tutorial on that and a I am quit new I can't figure it out yet

Comment: @Zash__ check this: [Changing the development language in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926728/8346251) maybe help you.