# Change Language section on published iOS App

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, appstore-approval

I've got finally got my German App approved from apple (after getting rejected several times) and this is what I see on appstore
[image]

my app language is set to English.

I have checked everywhere, wherever I could change the language. In the **App Information** screen 
[image]

and in the iOS App tab 
[image]

Kindly let me know how to fix this issue.
How to change language from English to German?
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## IMPORTANT:

Languages display in the App Store and primary language is totally different.

**Which languages are displayed in AppStore?**

> Languages which are display in-app store are the list of language
> support by your application, That means if you want to include german
> language then you have to put `localise.string` file for german
> language. English is a base language for any application by default.

I have already worked with an application, Which is supported multilanguage (8 Language). I have attached the screenshot below. How it is displayed in-app store.

[image]

## Solution:

Just add localization file for german language then resubmit it. Then automatically german display languages list.

## OR

You can change the language in the App store by changing the base language in the project setting. For Reference find the below screenshot.

[image]

## Reference:

[Changing the development language in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871815/changing-the-development-language-in-xcode)

[Video tutorial for changing development language](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n5BS0cJOkvnURMDzk2IDlVP1oQTw5-9i/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Alright, Thanks A lot for this answer. I've been looking for it everywhere, but couldn't find.
@Hitesh Surani , How about I need only german language? Will English be displayed then too?

Comment: @TalhaAhmadKhan Please check update may be it is help you

Comment: Ok great, so after adding german and removing English, will I have to add localize.string file? 
I am asking in details so to be careful because I won't be able to know it unless the app gets published. :/

Comment: I think as of now there is no need to create localize.string file. Will update my answer later

Comment: OK I got your update. Thanks bro