# Add English localization to non-English app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I want to add English language to my app, because right now the app is only Swedish language. Under the "Project" and "Localizations" there is already English there:

[image: Image here] .

So all the text I have in my app is in Swedish, but I also want to add English. I do have many `.swift` files with many strings and arrays:

[image: Image here]

Any tips how I can do this? I have seen a few tutorials, but in those they started from a new project, and the base language was English, but for me it is Swedish. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871815/changing-the-development-language-in-xcode and update your project to set Swedish as the Development Language. Then you can add English.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, just got that that working when I saw your comment. But now, how can I add English language for all my `.swift` files? There are arrays that contains over 100-200 strings in each one of them.

Comment: See the [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html). It's older and based on Objective-C but the concepts are the same with Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy I think Obj-c tutorials are hard to follow, since I have ever used or understood that language. But do I have to manually translate every single line, or does this happen automatically?

Comment: @Rango You will need to translate each *unique* line, so if you use "Help" five times, then only one translation is required. The only automatic translation is of system provided values, such as the "Done" or "Cancel" buttons.

Comment: @CodeBender But I don't understand how I am going to get all localized, since I have so many `.swift` files.

Comment: @Rango - can you give an example of the text you're trying to localise?

Comment: @Rango if you haven't used `NSLocalizedString` everywhere so far, you'll have to manually update all your code to do so. (But if you have, all you have to do is to provide translations for the keys in the strings file.)