# iTunes Connect - Primary Language question

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

So my apps Primary Language is currently Norwegian in iTunes Connect, but in the new version I have added localization for English language. When I test on my device and set language to Sweden (just for testing), it still shows Norwegian. But what I want is to have English language in the app in all countries, and Norwegian only for Norway. Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Hey Kidrik, are you talking about the language of the text in the app or the description in iTunes Connect?

Comment: @ahbou I mean the language of the text in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Base language in the project as default language for other localizations not supported by your app. Means, if you want Norwegian as default for other localizations, then under localizations for your Localizable.strings select "Base" which will generate Base.lproj folder and a localization file. Just make sure you have Norwegian strings in that file, Xcode may choose English in that file, just copy paste Norwegian content and replace. It should work fine.

Comment: I used Xcode on Norwegian, but recreated the project in Xamarin C# for iOS and Android with localization. So the final localized version will be from Xamarin. But if I set Primary Language in iTunes Connect to English U.S. Will all the countries except from Norway have English language?

Comment: This setting in iTunes Connect is for the iTunes page, not the app.

Answer (score 0):

Itunes Connect language has not effect on the language in the app.

If you want to change the app language you need to set the base localization to english as explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232581/3698961